# Adding new facts to a file in Prolog

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

I have a problem in Prolog regarding adding new facts to the file 'relations.pl'. Every time I get facts I save them and I use

```
tell('relations.pl').
listing(relation).
told.
```

The only problem is that I want to insert the new facts and avoid storing the same facts more that one if there are any.

Is there anyway to do this?
Thank you,

Comment: You could append text to a file, but be warned, this easily leads to a lot of errors and inconsistencies. Instead write it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more robust to say `out_tofile(listing(relation),'relation.pl').` The only inplace operation for textfiles is to append new text to them. I cannot recommend doing this here. Appending would be fine for logfiles.

```
:- meta_predicate
      out_tofile(0,+),             % out_tofile(:,+) in older versions
      out_ontofile(0,+),           % idem
      out_tostream__andclose(0,+). % idem

out_tofile(Goal, File) :-
   open(File,write,Stream),
   out_tostream__andclose(Goal, Stream).

out_ontofile(Goal, File) :-
   open(File,append,Stream),
   out_tostream__andclose(Goal, Stream).

out_tostream__andclose(Goal, Stream) :-
   current_output(Stream0),
   call_cleanup((set_output(Stream),once(Goal)), set_output_close(Stream0, Stream)).

set_output_close(Stream0, Stream) :-
   set_output(Stream0),
   close(Stream).
```